# save values from textbox to xml document

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, textbox, xmldocument

I want to save my webpage in XML format. I thought of using XmlDocument to save the values. I tried searching it but I couldn't find a proper way for saving the data entered in a textbox to the xml document.

Is there any way? Although incorrect, but this is what I've done till now.

```
 XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();


        // Create root node.
        XmlElement XElemRoot = XDoc.CreateElement("Generate_License");

        //Add the node to the document.
        XDoc.AppendChild(XElemRoot);


        XmlElement Xsource = XDoc.CreateElement("General_Info", txtGInfo.ToString());
        XElemRoot.AppendChild(Xsource);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of entered data and your expected XML file please?

Comment: the data entered in the general info would be alphanumeric and there is no particular format for xml.

Comment: there should be some format in which u will be saving data...

Comment: So if what you want is to save a string in a file, why do you want to use XML? A simple text file won't be enough?

Comment: it's not just string. This is just the first element. I have a proper web page containing dropdownlists, radio buttons and text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with - based on `InnerText` property

```
// Create the xml document containe
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();// Create the XML Declaration, and append it to XML document
XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
doc.AppendChild(dec);// Create the root element

XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Generate_License");

XmlElement elem= doc.CreateElement("General_Info");
elem.InnerText =txtGInfo.Text;

root.AppendChild(elem);
doc.AppendChild(root);
```

Comment: it's working but the output isn't showing what I've entered in the textbox. In the general info, it's giving me this `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`.

Comment: Syrion Yes i copied your code entered because i don't know your need,  but replace with Text property, Happy that you solved your problem

Comment: I'am happy to help you Syrion

Answer (score 0):

try this,this is very simple. just that you will need 4.0 .net framework

```
XDocument doc =
  new XDocument(
    new XElement("Generate_License",
      new XElement("General_Info", txtGInfo.ToString())

      )
    )
  );
```